# RailsTutorial chap3 3.7 rspec error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm following the RailsTutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#fig-green_passing_spec and I'm receiving an error when I run:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

I get the following output:

```
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
B:/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from B:/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from B:/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from B:/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from B:/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from B:/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from B:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Here is the gemfile I'm using:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I completed chapter 3 a month ago with no issues. The only change between then and now has been the update to rails due to the exploit that was exposed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what I should change/look at?

Comment: as far as I can tell from the gemfile I'm using rspec-rails 2.11.0

Comment: The spec-rails gem may have been updated when you updated rails. A few months ago I completed the same chapter without problems, until rspec 2.0 got released, and suddenly I got errors about missing methods. It's a hunch, but did you try moving the specs from `spec/requests/` to `spec/features/`?

Answer (score 0):

Compare it with [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-final_gemfile) then re-run `bundle install`?